# Multi-Site setup and Single domain configuration

Tags: multisite

When configuring a multi-site solution on Sitecore 7.2 Update 2, the client has decided to switch to a single domain. I would like to keep it as a multi-site solution in case the client decides for two domains in the future. There is minimal content that is shared across the sites.

I know that I can use https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Multiple_Sites_Manager.aspx. I am looking for other possible solutions as well.

The Sitecore Tree is:

```
sitecore
  |_content
       |_Personal
       |_Business
       |_Dictionaries
```

The Dictionaries are setup

```
Dictionaries
       |_Personal Dictionary : Fallback Global
       |_Business Dictionary : Fallback Global
       |_Global Dictionary
```

The sites configuration is below:

```
<site name="personal" 
            hostName="www.mydomain.com" 
            targetHostName="www.mydoman.com"
            virtualFolder="/" 
            physicalFolder="/" 
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/personal" 
            dictionaryDomain="{UniquePersonalDictionaryDomain}"
            patch:before="site[@name='modules_website']"/>
      <site name="business" 
            hostName="business.mydomain.com" 
            targetHostName="business.mydomain.com"
            virtualFolder="/" 
            physicalFolder="/" 
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/business" 
            startItem="/Home" database="web" 
            domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" 
            cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
            registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" 
            xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
            enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" 
            dictionaryDomain="{UniqueToBusinessDictionary}" 
            enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
        <site name="website">
            <patch:attribute
                 name="rootPath">/sitecore/content/public</patch:attribute
            <patch:attribute name="dictionaryDomain">{UniqueToBusinessDictionary}</patch:attribute>
        </site>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How to configure a multi-site solution with a single domain. Instead of using www.mydomain.com and business.mydomain.com, I would like to use to www.mydomain.com for both sites.

Comment: What are you expecting as a functional  URL for both sites?  Something has  to differentiate the other.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. As a functional URL for both sites, we should see www.mydomain.com. After more troubleshooting, overriding the ItemResolver, I can achieve the expected result. My question is, is it possible to have 2 sites in the content tree and one URL? If so, what does the configuration look like?

Answer (score 6):

If you will have the same domain but different rootPath, you will need to make use of the `virtualFolder` and `physicalFolder` attribute in the sitedefinition.config.

The virtualFolder and physicalFolder will allow you to use the same domain but having different sites that hits different rootPath. This will allow you to have less coding.

Site Definition Example:

[image]

Once the Site Definition is setup, patch the Sitecore setting `AlwaysStripLanguage` to set the value to false as shown below:

From

```
<setting name=”Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage” value=”true”/>
```

To

```
<setting name=”Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage” value=”false”/>
```

You may check my blog post how to setup it here: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/sitecore-multi-sites-with-same-domain-but-different-sitecore-item-node/